# Would it be possible for a cylindrical magnet suspended vertically down from a hanging magnet to levitate in static equilibrium?

Tags: electromagnetism, newtonian-gravity, magnetic-fields, thought-experiment

Let's assume that a cylindrical magnet is clamped by an horizontal arm extending out of the wall. The top of the magnet is its north pole and the smooth face facing down is its south pole. If I bring another cylindrical magnet and position it perfectly in line below the fixed magnet, with its top being its north pole and the bottom being the south pole, would it be possible that the weight of the magnet going down and the magnetic force attempting to pull the magnet upwards balance out so that the magnet can levitate in mid air?

Conceptually, it seems to make sense as in this case, the magnet is not prone to flipping since it poles facing each other are not repelling. However, I'm not sure if this violates Earnshaw's theorem.

It it's not possible, then why isn't it possible? Did I miss something in my assumptions? And if it is possible, Is it also possible for the levitating magnet to rotate about its central vertical axis and still remain suspended in space?

Comment: I imagine such a position is an unstable equilibrium...too low and the magnetic force loses to gravity while being too high it overcomes gravity. It would have to be placed there with an impossible level of precision.

Comment: @Triatticus Makes sense. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Earnshaw's theorem doesn't say that you can't have equilibrium;  it says that you can't have *stable* equilibrium.

There's a point below the fixed magnet where the attraction it exerts on the "floating" magnet exactly cancels out the force of the floating magnet's weight.  But if the floating magnet is perturbed ever so slightly downwards from this point, then the upwards magnetic force will decrease;  and since the weight remains the same, there will be a net downward force and the floating magnet will fall.  Similarly, if the floating magnet is perturbed ever so slightly upwards, the magnetic force increases. In that case you end up with a net upwards force on the floating magnet, and it will probably end up colliding with the fixed magnet.